# Spring AMQP unable to connect back to RabbitMQ server after rabbitMQ server is restarted

Tags: spring-amqp

Our application is able to connect to RabbitMQ server, messages get received in the message listeners, everything works fine. But when RabbitMQ is restarted then, we get below exception in the logs and messages are not received in the listeners. Once we restart our application container as well, then everything starts working. We cannot restart our application in Prodcution environment and we want the application to be able to recover connection to RabbitMQ once RabbitMQ server is up. Can someone please help.

```
2018-05-10 09:10:01,561[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-34]|DEBUG|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|13-org.springframework.beans-3.1.4.RELEASE|Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue#3'
2018-05-10 09:10:01,560[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-27]|DEBUG|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer|435-wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar-0.0.0|Closing Rabbit Channel: null
2018-05-10 09:10:01,563[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-34]|DEBUG|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer|435-wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar-0.0.0|Starting consumer Consumer: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=MANUAL local queue size=0
2018-05-10 09:10:01,560[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-32]|DEBUG|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|13-org.springframework.beans-3.1.4.RELEASE|Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue#1'
2018-05-10 09:10:01,559[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-29]|WARN|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer|435-wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar-0.0.0|Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:54)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:195)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:371)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:365)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1009)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)[:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)[:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)[:1.7.0_80]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)[432:com.rabbitmq.client:4.3.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:61)[432:com.rabbitmq.client:4.3.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)[432:com.rabbitmq.client:4.3.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:925)[432:com.rabbitmq.client:4.3.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:884)[432:com.rabbitmq.client:4.3.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:842)[432:com.rabbitmq.client:4.3.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1026)[432:com.rabbitmq.client:4.3.0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:191)[435:wrap_file_._jetstream_thirdparty_spring-rabbit-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:0]
    ... 7 more
```

This exception seems wierd to me because, if RabbitMQ is refusing connections then, how is the connection established when we do an application restart.
This issue is giving me a very hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1.3.6` is too old and out of support version. Would be great if you consider to upgrade to the latest one: https://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/, at least `1.7.7` . Also read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#auto-recovery.